# firebase swift 3 conversion : Cannot convert value of type '(_) -> ()' to expected argument type '((Error) -> Void)?

Tags: firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I convert my code to swift 3 , and Im getting the following error when trying to read some data:

Cannot convert value of type '(_) -> ()' to expected argument type '((Error) -> Void)?'

```
Ref.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
   print(snapshot)
}, withCancel: { error in  //the error appear here
        print(error.description)
})
```

Comment: Xcode acts weirdly sometimes when interacting with firebase... Try setting explicitly the types of the snapshot and the error.
`ref.observe(.value, with: { (snap: FIRDataSnapshot) in  
 }, withCancel: { (error: Error) in
 })`

Comment: post it as an answer , I'll accept it , THANKS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comment you have to set the types. I am really glad I helped you. Thank you for your appreciation. Happy coding.

```
ref.observe(.value, with: { (snap: FIRDataSnapshot) in }, withCancel: { (error: Error) in })
```